# Как настроить проект на Django + Nginx для перенаправления на https?

Tags: django, nginx, https, cloudflare

Есть проект написанный на Django и стоит он на https, как правильно настроить https и какие для этого нужны дополнительные библиотеки или модули, SSL лежит на cloudlflare

Comment: Если на Cloudflare, то ничего и никакие